# Elasticsearch high level rest client more than 1 field search

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, rest-client

I am using Scala 2.12 to query the ElasticSearch (6.5).

I am able to use querybuilders for a single field search like below:

```
val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
val qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
      .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname", "01_.+_20190711_data"))
searchSourceBuilder.query(qb)
```

Using the above (I need regex search) I can search the relevant documents.

However, I have more complex requirement, where I have to match the documents on more than one field-value pair.

i.e.

header.fieldname should match pattern "01_.+*data"
AND
header.fieldname2 should match pattern "type*.+_2019-07-11"

Basically, it is like SQL where clause on 2 or more columns (and value string).

I was checking https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

But this is like searching the same string (value) in multiple fields. This is NOT what I want.
I basically want something like SQL AND in where clause (better if it is with regex too).

**UPDATE:**

Please note the below answer by @Meet Rathod works and accepted.

However, to take it forward, so if I need one more condition which is SQL OR, is my below code correct.
Required:

```
header.fieldname: 01_.+data AND header.fieldname2: type.+_2019-07-11 AND (header.fieldname3: some_thing OR header.fieldname3: some_other_thing)
```

Code:

```
val qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
      .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname", "01_.+_20190711_data"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname2", "type.+_2019-07-11"))
.should(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname3", "some_thing"))
.should(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname3", "some_other_thing"))
```

Is this correct or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want only those document which satisfies **all** your conditions should list out in the result. And if that's the case I believe adding another must clause in your query should get your expected result. The raw query will look something like this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "header.fieldname": "01_.+data"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "header.fieldname2": "type.+_2019-07-11"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure but, your Scala code should look something like this.

```
val qb = new BoolQueryBuilder()
      .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname", "01_.+_20190711_data"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("header.fieldname2", "type.+_2019-07-11"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I was looking for putting more than one condition for the Querybuilder.